# Using a custom request in @Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller

I have a controller which look like this

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "export")
public Object exportUsers( @Context HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model ) throws IOException
{
    String target = request.getParameter( RequestParametersConstantsCommons.TARGET );
    String entityName = request.getParameter( RequestParametersConstantsCommons.ENTITY_NAME );

    return new SCSuccessResponse();
}
```

Problem is, i need a custom HttpServletRequest (for some operation).
Is there a way to do it except extends the DispatcherServlet and transform my request in the new servlet ? 
Thx !

Comment: Can you give some details about your custom `HttpServletRequest`?

Comment: Well, i'm use to replace an httpServletRequest by my CustomServletRequest, but i'm usually doing it in my CXFServlet. Here i have to use a DispatcherServlet. And what do you want to know about my request ?